# How to get signed_request in Unity facebook webgl api?

Tags: javascript, facebook, unity-game-engine

I have facebook auth on my site with unity webgl game. 
If i use javascript facebook api, i can get it from FB.getLoginStatus callback in  response.authResponse.signedRequest. 
How to get signedRequest in unity facebook api?